# Joomla 2.5 PHP error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserStateFromRequest() on a non-object in com_upman/models/upman.php on line 338

Tags: php, joomla

i am using joomla 2.5 with virtuemart 2.0.0 and OSE Checkout plugin
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserStateFromRequest() on a non-object in components/com_upman/models/upman.php on line 338

please explain how to remove this error.

Thanks....

Comment: That's something you should check with the OSE ticket desk. Having dealt with them a few times I've found that they are very responsive and helpful + you have support with this since it's a commercial plugin. Bet they'd have an answer for you quickly. https://www.opensource-excellence.com/my-support-tickets.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will you please tell me how to remove ose from joomla, and will you please also help me to configure Google Checkout out in Gavick's mystore.

Answer (score 0):

in your joomla directory, goto all:
 admin/components/com_{component name} folders and remove or rename the files like admin.{component name}.php
that should fix it